# Python virtual environment, is full python install also required?

Tags: python, .net-core

I am new to Python, do you have to install Python on a server even though you have copied over a virtual environment folder (.venv)? I was working under the impression if I simply provided the path to the virtual folder it would have everything it needed, libs etc. More details below thanks.

I have a requirement to call a python program from a .net core api running inside IIS on windows server. This is a temporary solution. I am using ProcessStartInfo in .net to call the python program and passing a few arguments and this works well locally, but when deployed instead of using the path I have supplied to the python virtual environment (see below) it is looking at C:\Users\{me}\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37. If I do not also supply Python at this location I get the error "Python not found".

Thanks

```
string pythonDirectory = @"D:\Services\python"; 

 ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
            start.FileName = pythonDirectory + @"\.venv\Scripts\python.exe"; // using virtual environment python.        
            start.Arguments = $"{prog} {arguments}";
            start.UseShellExecute = false; // Do not use OS shell
```

Comment: You would have the libraries but the main python executable is still required. I.e. you still need python. Venv helps to ensure that a project library and dependencies don't affect anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a Python installation to provide a Python binary, copied or symlinked. The first sections (Motivation and Specification) of this [PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0405/) give details :

> Thus, a Python virtual environment in its simplest form would consist of nothing more than a copy or symlink of the Python binary accompanied by a pyvenv.cfg file and a site-packages directory.